# Way to render any component in extjs on fly

Tags: extjs, plugins, components, containers, render

1. I am provided with built in extjs components classes.
2. I cannot change them as i am working on plugin.
3. I cannot override them as there are certain things which cannot be
   predefined.
4. And also I want to change component for particular case, not all
   cases.
5. Now If it will be possible that I pick that component from DOM,
   change it any of property and render it there onwards. If it could
   be done, then my work become lot easy.

Its completely a scenario. But still for ease in understanding, I am adding a sample code.

```
var tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
                    width : 300,
                    height : 200,
                    activeTab : 0,
                    items : [
                        {
                            title : 'Tab1',
                            bodyPadding : 10,
                            items : [
                                {
                                    xtype : 'button',
                                    text : 'B1'
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            title : 'Tab2',
                            items : [
                                {
                                    xtype : 'button',
                                    text : 'B2'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
                    autoRender : true
                });
                // Change title of tab panel
                tabPanel.items.each(function(item) {
                    item.title = "text"+Math.random();
                });
```

Now I want to remove this already rendered tab panel. And want to render it upon my choice wherever i want.

Comment: I hope now problem is more clear to you @JohnKrull

Answer (score 0):

After lot of search, I find solution to problem. We can use doLayout() or update() function of component to fulfill purpose.